# Retrieving private method information using Javassist

Tags: javassist

I am using JavaAssist to read class information. It is a good and very useful tool.
However, what I have noticed is that it does enumerate or returns the private methods of the class.

Is there a way I can retrieve private methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **CtClass.getDeclaredMethods( )** to get the information about private methods. 
Or as suggested above reflection works fine.
Try giving [this](http://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) a read to know more about the features of javassist.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get all the methods, which also contains the private methods of a a class you could use reflection:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class ExampleClass {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      ExampleClass cls = new ExampleClass ();
      Class c = cls.getClass();

      // returns the array of Method objects 
      Method[] m = c.getDeclaredMethods();
      for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
         System.out.println("method found = " + m[i].toString());
      }
   }

   public ExampleClass () {
      // no argument constructor
   }   

   public void publicMethod(String string1) {
      // NOPE
   }

   private void privateMethod(Integer i) {
      // NOPE
   }
}
```